# How to find the last element of the array

Tags: php

I am trying to find the last element in the array by using foreach loop.

I have..

```
  foreach ( $employees as $employee ) {

         $html.=$employee ->name.'and ';

  }
```

I don't want to add 'and' to the last employee. Are there anyways to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's another way, I suppose:

```
$html = implode(' and ', 
  array_map(function($el) { return $el->name; }, $employees));
```

It's simple: [**array_map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) will create an array of `$employee->name` elements, and [**implode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will make a string from these, using `' and '` string as 'glue'. )

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner approach than having a counter in your foreach could be to simply remove the final "and " off of your string.

```
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    $html .= $employee->name . 'and ';
}
$html = substr($html, 0, strlen($html) - 4);
```